# No Internet access, Spring XSD's reqeuired?

Tags: spring, citrus-framework

I am trying to run some Citrus tests in an environment without Internet access. My test is a subclass of TestNGCitrusTestBuilder. Now, when I run the tests, I am getting this error message:

```
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/consol/citrus/spring/root-application-ctx.xml]
Mär 01, 2018 9:50:18 AM org.springframework.util.xml.SimpleSaxErrorHandler warning
WARNING: Ignored XML validation warning
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 26; columnNumber: 29; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
```

The XML document causing the problem is located in citrus-core-1.4.jar. The root element looks like this:

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

So, the XML parser is right to request access to this documents. Question: How can I activate some Resolver, or whatever, which makes the XML parser load from a local resource?

Answer (score 0):

Citrus 1.4? This is almost four years old. No chance to update to a newer version? 2.7.3 is the latest Citrus version. I am positive that the issues are gone with newer versions of Citrus and Spring.

However make sure that you have `spring-aop` dependency in your project classpath. Usually Spring will resolve the schema locations within the classpath as `spring.handlers` and `spring.schemas` are packaged in META-INF within the Spring jar files. Although I am not sure how the old versions of Spring behave on this.